# Computer does not resume from sleep, troubles booting up

Tags: suspend

I have an HP Pavilion laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. Since I moved over to Ubuntu, I've been having issues with my laptop's sleep mode.

Whenever I sleep the computer, it would leave the screen on, but blank it of all data. In order to escape this mode, I need to forcefully power down my computer using the power button.

Similarly, upon an attempted boot, my system will often drop into a similar behavior where it will power on, display a purple screen, and then get stuck in suspend mode again. If I keep restarting the machine, it will occasionally jump back into working.

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: When you are able to log in, is there anything interesting in the /var/log/syslog? is this a fresh install or any notable packages/programs installed?  Can you give more stats about the hardware of the laptop.

Comment: I have only performed the standard updates. However, before I updated, this was not a problem. I tried a new install and the same thing happened. As soon as the updates were completed I started experiencing these problems. I believe it is the Nividia drives, but am not sure. I know it has an AMD processor, not sure on the other stuff...I could look next time I have to go through the startup.

Comment: I had similar issue with my desktop. No concrete answer, but reinstall fixed it. Make sure u install with 16.04.2 natively to get latest kernel and hardware updates. Otherwise you have to manually request hardware updates for 16.04.0 and 16.04.1. There is a command for that but i am not able to look it up now.  I agree, probably related to nvidia drivers.  I don't have amd processor but seems like i see lots of amd+nvidia woes on this site.